# Antonym of coterminous, or single word for "having the same beginning"

Tags: single-word-requests

I find myself wanting to say that two things have their beginning together (not necessarily in time). The word *coterminous* came to mind, but that is the opposite of what I'm trying to say. I thought of *simultaneous*, but that is too punctiliar (whereas I want to express something more enduring, as implied by the word *coterminous*) and perhaps a little too time-laden.

So, for example:

> To know the truth and to begin to know that you know the truth are `<things-originating-inseparably>`.

Is there a single English word for this?

Comment: ***Cognate*** means 'born together'. [The etymology is shown here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf). Mostly it's used for words that come from the same original source, like _father_ and _paternal_, but there's no reason why it couldn't be used for other concepts, if they spring from a common source.

Comment: Just a note: Coterminous does not mean "having the same ending" even it looks like that, so the antonym of coterminous does not suggest "having the same beginning". And ironically, its antonym is "separate".

Comment: @ermanen Hm, interesting. Did it mean that historically? I sometimes learn my big words from old books, though I can't say where exactly I picked up "coterminous".

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=coterminous) says that it is a malformed word but you also need to check the etymology of terminal. The word suggests the meaning of "meeting at the ends" but it is used when two things share the same boundary. The origin and usage of this word could be a whole new question :)

Answer (score 4):

> **coöriginal** or **cooriginal** (not comparable)
>
> (philosophy) Existing together ab initio; equiprimordial.
>
> (geometry, of a line) Originating from the same point in space.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co%C3%B6riginal#English)

Comment: "Equiprimordial" a pretty good answer to this question in its own right. I'm going to try to fit that one into conversations more often.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "[**concomitant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant)" and "[**coincidental**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coincidental)."

> **concomitant**: happening at the same time as something else.
>
> [**coincidental**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincidental) and [**coincident**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincident): existing or occurring at the same time; occupying the same space or time.
>
> *To know the truth and to begin to know that you know the truth are **coincidental***.

Comment: *Coincidental* is almost exclusively used with its other meaning, so is perhaps not the best choice. Maybe *co-incidental* would get the "happening together" meaning across better?

Comment: I'm not surprised if you can't find the hyphenated spelling - *coincidental* **is** the correct spelling, after all. But adding a hyphen would emphasize the "*co-* = together" part of the etymology/derivation of this word, and therefore would de-emphasize the "remarkable chance" connotation.

Comment: @Marthaª I think the other meaning of "coincidental" should be hyphenated. It makes more sense to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

- *contemporaneous*: Existing or occurring in the same period of time.
- *coeval*: Having the same age or date of origin.
- *concomitant*: Naturally accompanying or associated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like one of these:

1. *[entwined](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/entwine?family=entwined)*
2. *[twinned](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/twinned)*
3. *[inextricably bound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inextricably)*

Yes, I realize the third choice there is two words.