# What is an adjective for multiple things originating from the same source?

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like there should be a word for this, and it seems like it's on the tip of my tongue, but I just can't think of it.

**Is there an adjective for when a number of things all originate from the same source?**

I'll give you an example. Suppose you knew a number of jokes. You learned all of these jokes from the same person. All of these jokes could be said to be (adjective). Uni-source-ic?

Another example. You have a number of electronic devices. They all came from the Apple Store down the street. These devices are (adjective).

One final example. Suppose you believed that all knowledge in the world came from God. You would say something like "I believe in the (adjective) nature of all of the world's knowledge".

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is there a special word for things you bought from Target? For things you bought online? For things you bought during Ramadan? For things you bought to give to nephews? No. English does not have an infinite number of words, though there are an infinite number of things there might be words for. Life is short.

Comment: The word I'm asking for differs from your examples by its broadness. The examples you bring up are ridiculous because they're absurdly specific -- I'm looking for a word that is considerably more abstract, more broad. I ask because I feel like there's a word on the tip of my tongue. No need to mock.

Comment: Well, in that case, _cognate_ may be your word. It means 'born together', and refers to words like _father_ and _paternal_ that both come from the same original root. _Cognate_ itself is [cognate with a whole lot of other English words](http://www.umich.edu/gen.pdf).

Comment: It reminded me of concurrent lines in geometry, they all originates/meet at the same point.

Comment: Related: [Antonym of coterminous, or single word for “having the same beginning”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169414/antonym-of-coterminous-or-single-word-for-having-the-same-beginning)

Comment: ["single source(d)"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/single-sourcing) works for the electronics example.

Comment: I like "spawn".  Would you accept a noun or a verb?  Example:  "All these devices were spawned at Apple."  "All these jokes are the spawn of Uni-source-ic". I won't touch you last example.

Answer (score 2):

The word [co-original](http://www.wordsense.eu/co%C3%B6riginal/) has this meaning (or coöriginal, if you're the *New Yorker*).

It's not a remotely common word but I think a lot of people would understand its meaning without the help of a dictionary.

Comment: co means together not the same

Comment: Yes, it's "originating together" rather than "having one origin".  If you were to coin a word for the latter it would be _unioriginal_ or _equioriginal_ ("mono" is a Greek root).

Comment: There are also a few occurrences of the variant "co-originative" returned by books.google.com, though nothing in the ngram viewer, so it seems fairly rare.

Answer (score 1):

For your first and third examples, I would suggest **related**. As with children or family members, it would apply to things with "the same parent".

As for the second, I believe the usual way to describing items which were all manufactured by a common manufacturer would be "X products" or "Apple products" in this case.

Answer (score -5):

**Definitions:**

mono --> one

sourced --> coming from

original

**mono original**  --> originating from one - one origin - one source

**Other uses of mono in compound with nouns:**

mono culture --> one culture

mono pol --> one pol

Comment: I can't make any sense of this answer. Would you like to edit it to make it clearer? Currently it risks being deleted.

Comment: did that help you?