# Single word expression for "having the same source"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word adjective to express the fact that two items are derived from the same source or origin. Examples are two photos of the same scene, or two descriptions of the same event.

I searched for "co-origin", which does not seem to be a word.  "cognate" is close, but most examples I could find are about linguistics and describe words that have a common *etymological* origin. I guess there are also words to indicate the same ancestry (which are also too specific).

*Is there a more generic word describing the relationship that two things are from the same source?*

Related:

[Antonym of coterminous, or single word for "having the same beginning"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169414)

-- Edit --

This question is not a duplicate of question I linked because I am looking for the word indicating two things are the images or reflections of the same thing, which is less direct than having the same ancestry or beginning (as stated in the question)

Comment: _Cognate_ is the term for words that come from the same source. It's Latin for 'born together', _co_ + _g(e)natus_, originally from  [the PIE root *_gen-_](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf).

Comment: A metaphor such as *siblings* may be used.

Comment: In some contexts, things deriving from the same source are said to be "congeners". The adjective form is apparently "congeneric" or "congenerous". However, it certainly wouldn't apply to photographs or descriptions of events.

Comment: _Sibling_'s defined senses given by [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sibling) actually bracket the required sense: << **sibling**
1: ... one of two or more individuals having one common parent
2: one of two or more things related by a common tie or characteristic – 
_the sedan's smaller sibling_ >> But not an ideal fit.

Comment: 'This question is not a duplicate of question I linked because I am looking for the word indicating two things are the images or reflections of the same thing, which is less direct than having the same ancestry or beginning' In that case, the title needs changing. Now, **coreferential** applies, 'referring to the same thing / person'.

Comment: You should edit more to make the distinction from the proposed duplicate more obvious. As it stands, the only thing that differentiates this question  from the other is your claim that they're not the same.